# How to merge two columns content identically labelled?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to merge same labelled column's content from one single dataset.

Starting from this :

```
Index  Name  Name  Name
0      Olaf  Olaf  Eddy
1      Jim   Lola  Olaf
```

To do, I tried this :

```py
df.set_index('Index').stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame('Name').reset_index()
```

Returned AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

I expect this :

```
Index  Name
0      Olaf
1      Jim
2      Olaf
3      Lola
4      Eddy
5      Olaf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) here (assuming `Index` is not a column but an index):

```
df.melt(value_name='Name').drop('variable',1)
```

---

```
   Name
0  Olaf
1   Jim
2  Olaf
3  Lola
4  Eddy
5  Olaf
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also construct a new DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(zip(*df.filter(like='Name').to_numpy())), 
             columns=['Name'])

#   Name
#0  Olaf
#1   Jim
#2  Olaf
#3  Lola
#4  Eddy
#5  Olaf
```

Comment: interesting idea. :D

Comment: `melt` is certainly easier to read :D. But this performs pretty well for moderately sized DataFrames. It starts to get slow for larger things.